# Prove $x_{n+1}+\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}>\sqrt{2n+4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $ \{x_n\}$ satisfy $x_1=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and
>   $x_{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{x_{n+1}}=2x_{n}+\dfrac{1}{x_n}.$ Show 
>   $x_{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{x_{n+1}}>\sqrt{2n+4}.$

Comment: Is there any approach or tools that are preferred or should be avoided?

Comment: Maybe this can be done by induction. But I want another method else. @LeeDavidChungLin

Answer (score 0):

By simple induction，we can obtain $a_n>0$. Denote $$y_n=x_n+\frac{1}{x_n},$$ then $y_n\geq 2$. Moreover, since $$y_n=x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}>\frac{1}{x_n},$$ then $ x_n>\frac{1}{y_n},$ Therefore $$y_{n+1}=y_n+x_n>y_n+\frac{1}{y_n}.$$ Thus $$y_{n+1}^2>y_{n}^2+\frac{1}{y_n^2}+2>y_n^2+2.$$ Hence $$ y_{n+1}^2-y_{n}^2>2.$$ Therefore $$y_{n+1}^2=y_1^2+\sum_{k=1}^n(y_{k+1}^2-y_k^2)> y_1^2+\sum_{k=1}^n 2=2n+\frac{25}{4}>2n+4,$$ which gives $$y_{n+1}>\sqrt{2n+4}.$$